# Refactoring a large method with many conditions - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this method:

#### method:

```
  def unassigned_workers?(users)
    assigned_users = []
    unassigned_users = []

    users.each do |user|
      if user.designated_to_assignment?(self)
        assigned_users << user
      else
        unassigned_users << user
      end
    end

    if unassigned_users.count > 0
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end
```

It's in my `Assignment` model. The assignment model has many `Users`, and basically what this method is trying to do is check if the user is designated to the assignment based on another relationship I have setup. It checks if the user is assigned and pushes it on the correct array. Does anybody know how I can refactor this to be smaller and more readable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using [any?](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/any%3F)

`assigned_users` not necessarily required.

```
 def unassigned_workers?(users)
    users.any? { |user| !user.designated_to_assignment?(self) }
 end
```

Comment: Good answer, but you're testing for unassigned.  Should be exclamation... `!user.designated_to_assignment?(self)`

Answer (score 2):

not sure why you have assigned_users at all
try:

```
  def unassigned_workers?(users)
    users.reject { |user| user.designated_to_assignment?(self) }.count > 0
  end
```

reject removes elements from a collection that match a predicate.

Moreover passing a self in a model as an argument is a code smell, maybe the dependencies are reversed

Comment: Maybe `#any?` instead of the `#count > 0`

Comment: Right there David.

Comment: @Nithin I don't think it really called for a new answer though. And you have the logic backwards.